# Align data cell value formula

Tags: excel

I would like to know if there's any available formula or way of doing this instead of manually dragging the cell.

My data looks like this:[image]
[image]

What I should be getting is like this above.

Is there any available way? Instead of dragging the cell one by one? I have big amount of data just like that. Would be happy for any solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: What is this? Excel? If yes you can do it with VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try the following code, which deletes empty cells.
(provided you change the search range to the desired)

```
Sub Del_Empty_cells()
    Dim cell, del, searchRng As Range
    Set searchRng = Range("A1:B10")
    Set del = Nothing
    For Each cell In searchRng.Cells
        If cell = 0 Or cell = "" Then
            If del Is Nothing Then
                Set del = cell
            Else
                Set del = Application.Union(del, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    If Not del Is Nothing Then del.Delete
End Sub
```